# How to get the collection location address (origin) of store

Tags: magento2

I am building an extension for Magento 2. I am trying to get the collection (origin) address of the store.

Answer (score 3):

Here what I tried and it's working:

```
    $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            "general/store_information/street_line1",
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
```

Answer (score -2):

**Please use below code it will give you address `customer id` wise.**

```
$customerId = $_POST["customer_id"];
$customer = $this->_customerRepository->getById($customerId);
$addresses = $customer->getAddresses();
```

Please note that getAddresses will return an array of `Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface`.

If you need the default billing address you can call:

```
$billingAddress = $customer->getDefaultBilling();
```

Thanks and Happy Coding.

Comment: Thank you, this will return the address of the customer, but I need the shipping address of the store.

Comment: Then you need to change getDefaultShipping(). Other code is same.